# PFC boost converter is not stepping up the voltage

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, boost, ac-dc, power-factor-correction

I am making a PFC circuit for AC-DC converter. I am facing a weird issue. As per my design the output of the circuit should be 390VDC, but I am getting 311VDCrms with ringing (overshoot 360V, undershoot 270V).

Here is my circuit (the red marks are the only differences between TI's circuit and my circuit, like, in TI circuit inductor is 2mH and in mine it is 0.56mH).
[image]

And this is the output waveform.

[image: Output waveform when Vcc is present to IC]

Here it is zoomed

[image: Here it is zoomed]

When I turned off Vcc to the controller IC, the output voltage of the circuit  is also 311VDC !!!!!

[image: Output waveform when Vcc is turned Off to IC]

Here is the input of pin 4 in oscilloscope

[image]

Here is output of pin 5 in oscilloscope

[image]

Here is input of pin 3 in oscilloscope

[image]

I am fully confused on what is happening. Please help me !!!!

Comment: What do the waveforms look like at the FET Gate and Drain, and pin 5 of U1? What are the voltages on pins 3,4,6 and 7 of U1?

Comment: On top of what Bruce is asking for, I'd like to see the current through your boost inductor. (Does TI even make this anymore? I can't find a datasheet) What is your switching frequency and your output power?

Comment: @BruceAbbott The pin 5 is giving a square wave ish output (like output is 99%duty cycle, it is mostly looking like a straight line is having a voltage dip and again turning on instantly) . but as per my knowledge it should be straight line. at the same time, The time between each ringing in the output is equal to the time between the each dip of the pin 5 output.

Comment: @Stiddily I cannot show you current waveform because I don't have a current probe at present. switching frequency is 65KHz. and output power designed for 350W at present. TI is making the part, here is the link for the datasheet ---- 
http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ucc28019a.pdf

Comment: "pin 5... is mostly looking like a straight line is having a voltage dip and again turning on instantly" - A picture is worth 1000 words. Show us the waveforms on pins 3, 4, and 5. Why did you reduce the inductor value to 560uH, and why did you not change the sense resistor to suit?

Comment: Pin 5 is the output of your compensation network, it should not have any sudden changes like that. A picture would definitely help. 350W @ 390V is less than 1 amp. The 560uH inductor is probably way too small. If you're in CrCM, your ripple current is going to be .9A (full output current). Putting your numbers into the Lbstmin equation from your datasheet gives a minimum inductance of closer to 1.5mH. This doesn't account for DC bias, so the actual inductance would be even higher than that.

Comment: @Stiddily actually I didn't found any readily available inductor with that value, that is why I have used 0.56mH. Actually in the excel sheet calculator provided by texas instruments, I can use the 0.56mH if I use different components, that is why i proceeded to give it, link for the calculator --> http://www.ti.com/lit/zip/SLUC117?jktype=tools_software

Comment: @BruceAbbott As I answered to stiddily's questiopn, I thought since the calculator provided by the texas instruments is saying I can use that value by changing other component's values, I decide to use those components.

Comment: Which other components did you have to change? The inductor value is based off of your maximum allowable ripple current, the voltage difference between input and output, and your switching frequency. That .56mH also becomes much lower once you apply DC bias. The DC bias loss is probably listed in the datasheet.

Comment: You posted pins 4 and 5, but definitely show pin 3. I have a feeling you're hitting OC each time you try to boost.

Comment: I think @Stiddily is right, you can't just replace the inductor for one which is almost 1/4 the value without also changing other parts of the circuit. You are probably hitting current limit every time the circuit tries to boost.

Comment: @Stiddily I have changed capacitor to 560uF as the calculator shown at least 472 uF has to be added If I changed boost inductor to 0.56mH

Comment: @Stiddily and vinzent I have also appended one 2mH as the evaluation board used 2mH obsolete inductor from vitec corp. (I mean I literally appended EVM board's inductor to my circuit) but still got same results.